# Access device's register i2c

Tags: c, linux, sensors, i2c, raspberry-pi3

I recently bought a [gy-521 board](http://playground.arduino.cc/uploads/Main/mpu-6050.jpg) and I'm trying to use it with a Raspberry Pi 3 through the following connections

```
RPi3     |     GY-521
---------------------
3.3V <-------> Vcc
GND  <-------> GND
SCL  <-------> SCL
SDA  <-------> SDA
```

Using `i2cdetect -y 1` I obtain the following

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

so the address of the device is 0x68. Reading the [datasheet](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Modules/Sensors/MOD-MPU6050/resources/RM-MPU-60xxA_rev_4.pdf) I found that for example the acceleration on the X axis is store in registers 3B (higher bits) and 3C (lower bits). My question is **how do I access those registers?**

My idea is that if I open `/dev/i2c-1` as a file descriptor, I can use the normal `read` and `write` functions. Then instead of getting data all the time, I can use `poll` in case of new available data.

I tried to use the `read` function as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface) but that's not working (I only get zeros) and when I use `poll` it seems like there's no one on the other side and the timeout (100ms) expires. I think I should say to the chip "give me the value of the 3B register" but I can't figure how to do it.

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <errno.h>

const char *filename = "/dev/i2c-1";
int DEBUG = 0;
int ADDRESS = 0x68;
struct pollfd pfd;

void debug(const char* format, ...)
{
    if (DEBUG)
    {
        va_list argptr;
        va_start(argptr, format);
        fprintf(stdout, "### ");
        vfprintf(stdout, format, argptr);
        va_end(argptr);
    }
}

void error_handler(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void set_debug(const char *deb_lev)
{
    unsigned long num;
    char *p;
    errno = 0;

    num = strtoul(deb_lev, &p, 10);

    if (errno != 0 || *p != '\0')
        error_handler("set_debug | strtoul");

    DEBUG = (num > 0);
}

int open_file(const char *filename)
{
    int fd;

    if ((fd = open(filename, O_RDWR)) == -1)
        error_handler("open_file | open");

    debug("\"%s\" opened at %d\n", filename, fd);
    return fd;
}

int8_t read_value(int fd)
{
    debug("Reading from %d\n", fd);

    int8_t num;
    char *p = (char *)&num;
    ssize_t size = sizeof(int8_t);
    ssize_t r = 0;

    while (size > 0)
    {
        if ((r = read(fd, p, size)) == -1)
            error_handler("read_value | read");

        size -= r;
        p += r;
    }

    return num;
}

void command(uint16_t reg, int fd)
{
    debug("Writing to %d\n", fd);

    unsigned char reg_buf[2];
    ssize_t w = 0;
    ssize_t size = sizeof(unsigned char)*2;

    reg_buf[0] = (reg >> 0) & 0xFF;
    reg_buf[1] = (reg >> 8) & 0xFF;

    if ((w = write(fd, reg_buf, size)) == -1)
        error_handler("command | write");
}

void read_data_from_imu(struct pollfd *pfd)
{
    int8_t val;
    int p;

    for (;;)
    {
        command(0x3b, pfd->fd);

        switch (p = poll(pfd, 1, 100))
        {
            case -1:
                error_handler("read_data_from_imu | poll");
            case 0:
                fprintf(stderr, "Timeout expired\n");
                break;
            default:
                val = read_value(pfd->fd);
                printf("Read: %u\n", val);
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s debug_flag\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    set_debug(argv[1]);

    pfd.fd = open_file(filename);

    debug("Setting slave address\n");
    if (ioctl(pfd.fd, I2C_SLAVE, ADDRESS) == -1)
        error_handler("main | ioctl");

    read_data_from_imu(&pfd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to [Kennyhyun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39411931/5025931) adding a `write` solved the problem.

So, if you want to read the **accelerometer measurement on the x axis**
you have to do something like this

```
...
#define ACCEL_XOUT_H 0x3b
#define ACCEL_XOUT_L 0x3c
...
write_register(ACCEL_XOUT_H, pfd->fd);
x_data = read_value(pfd->fd);
write_register(ACCEL_XOUT_L, pfd->fd);
x_data = (x_data << 8) + read_value(pfd->fd);
...
```

**EDIT 2**

Furthermore, you can simplify the code reading directly for 2 bytes after the write. You'll get something like this (error handling omitted)

```
int8_t buff[2];
write_register(ACCEL_XOUT_H, pfd->fd);
read(pfd->fd, buff, 2); //in this way you'll read both the ACCEL_XOUT_H register and the ACCEL_XOUT_L (the next one).
```

Comment: According to communication protocol in [this datasheet, chapter 9](http://www.dipmicro.com/?datasheet=PS-MPU-6000A-00v3.4.pdf), you should write only a single byte (the register address) to I2C (slave address is provided by the interface you linked to), then either read one byte and repeat for each register, or burst read multiple bytes. Only burst read guarantees correct multi-byte values, as the registers are free to update when I2C is idle. You're  writing 2 bytes, the register address and a zero byte, then reading 1 byte. Someone familiar with the interface is free to correct me.

Comment: What did you have to include for write_register?  I'm trying to do the same thing with a different I2c device?

Comment: I don't have the code anymore, but I think it was just a fancy wrapper for the `command` function above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to understand the basic of i2c.

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva704/slva704.pdf

3.2 Reading From a Slave On The I2C Bus

[image]

to read I2C register, you need to write slave addr, register addr and again slave addr and then read the data from the bus.
but it is done by the driver.
and the slave address is set in fd by ioctl.
but you still need to write register addr.

from your link..

```
/* Using SMBus commands */
  res = i2c_smbus_read_word_data(file, reg);
  if (res < 0) {
    /* ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed */
  } else {
    /* res contains the read word */
  }
```

`i2c_smbus_read_word_data` has `reg` which contains register addr.
but read() is not.
you need to `write(reg)` and then can `read()`.

and you need to only read 1 byte unless using burst mode or something.
it reads 1 byte since `size` is 1. but meaningless while and p++.

you are writing 3b before reading by `command(0x3b, pfd->fd);`.
but it will be like writing

```
68 > 3B , 68 > 00 , 68 <
```

and trying to read. (where > for the read bit, 0, < for 1)
maybe you need just `write(pfd->fd, 0x3b, 1)` instead of `command`.

Comment: Ok, I just put a `write` like you said, and now seems to work. Thank you very much. I'll go edit my question with the current solution.

Answer (score 2):

`i2cdetect` is from the i2c-tools project.  It's likely you also have `i2cget` already, which would work if you just need a command-line program to read a register.  You could also modify for your needs and recompile from source: [link to Github](https://github.com/groeck/i2c-tools/tree/master/tools)